# Change firefox homepage programatically

Tags: firefox

I need to set the home page of firefox upon user creation.  I use the following method:

1. Create a new firefox profile
2. Find the path to the new firefox profile
3. Add the line `user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "https://myhomepage.com")` to the `user.js` file in the new profile path.

This works every time except for the first.  When opened for the first time, firefox opens the default homepage.  If I then close and reopen the browser I see the homepage I set above.

How can I get this behaviour with the first time firefox opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to achieve this was by adding the relevant code to the `user.js` file of the **default** profile, as opposed to creating a new profile, this was not required.

Mozilla documentation and even the comments in the `prefs.js` state that any changes to the file will be overwritten when firefox starts and to use the `user.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

On each start of Firefox the file `user.js` is read after the file `prefs.js`,
and overrides corresponding settings in `prefs.js`.
If you close and restart Firefox then the current settings are saved in `prefs.js`,
so the lines in `prefs.js` and `user.js` will now be the same.

This might be the reason for your problem. To avoid it, perhaps the
solution is to also modify `prefs.js` before the first Firefox call.

Comment: If I change the prefs.js file firefox, on opening, overwrites the file and my addition is lost.  There does not seem to be a "browser.startup.homepage" in the prefs.js file

Comment: Added the solution I found to work as the answer but up voted yours as it did help me.